# array filter for array values

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-filter

i have this code which does the job for searching option name how can i use it to search the option value from array.

```
$productspp ='[{
    "id": 4674388066436,
    "title": "1st march",
    "options": [{
        "id": 6046836162692,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "Size",
        "position": 1,
        "values": ["12", "24", "36"]
    }, {
        "id": 6067871875204,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "z",
        "position": 2,
        "values": ["blue", "green"]
    }, {
        "id": 6067871907972,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "Material",
        "position": 3,
        "values": ["silk", "cotton"]
    }],
}, {
    "id": 4674394325124,
    "title": "2nd march",
    "options": [{
        "id": 6046844190852,
        "product_id": 4674394325124,
        "name": "Title",
        "position": 1,
        "values": ["Default Title"]
    }],
}, {
    "id": 4679851704452,
    "title": "3rd marchhh",
    "options": [{
        "id": 6053112545412,
        "product_id": 4679851704452,
        "name": "Title",
        "position": 1,
        "values": ["Default Title"]
    }]
}]';

$array = json_decode($productspp,1);

    $filter_name555 ='options';
    $dummytstt ='values';
    $filter_value=  blue;


 $expected = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($filter_name555, $dummytstt, $filter_value) {

    return ( stripos($el[$filter_name555][0][$dummytstt], $filter_value) !== false ); 
}

});
```

if the user searched option_value and it matches then it should list that product so in this case if user searches silk then it should list that product else not

for option name it works for option value it does not work as stripos expect it to be string but here in data it is array.

we tried in_array also to filter but that also did not work

when we search anything like 12 or 24 or 36 or blue or green then it should list this part of json. i mean this product and the code i have given above does the same but for option name. u can see that option value is array. it can have more than one values so my code is failing.

```
{
    "id": 4674388066436,
    "title": "1st march",
    "options": [{
        "id": 6046836162692,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "Size",
        "position": 1,
        "values": ["12", "24", "36"]
    }, {
        "id": 6067871875204,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "z",
        "position": 2,
        "values": ["blue", "green"]
    }, {
        "id": 6067871907972,
        "product_id": 4674388066436,
        "name": "Material",
        "position": 3,
        "values": ["silk", "cotton"]
    }],
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your desired result is. Can you edit the question and add an example?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes i am doing

Comment: Your problem is that you have a multidimensional array and you hardcoded `[0]` in your callback condition, meaning you only check the first element in `'options'`. Your algorithm doesn't work for name either, try searching for "Material" with it.

Comment: @El_Vanja for material we have added two more checks with 1 and 2 so all three are checked. we have used ||

Comment: Is `$productspp` generated dynamically or is it static?

Comment: @El_Vanja dynamic

Comment: Then you can't hardcode values. You need to iterate every level and `array_filter` only iterates the given level (won't go into sublevels).

Comment: @El_Vanja options are limited to three only

Comment: Still, you can't hardcode all three or you'll end up with some "undefined index" notices when less options exist. By the way, is the value search supposed to be case insensitive as well?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes it can be case insensitive for that we use stripos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish between an array value or regular value, because they need to be matched differently.

One thing you could do is write logic for if a value is an array, and then force any other kind of value into an array of just one element.

```php
$key = 'options';
$attr = 'values';
$search = 'blue';

$expected = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($key, $attr, $search) {
  $values = $el[$key];
  if (is_array($value)) {
    $values = array_column($value, $attr);
  } else {
    $value = array($value);
  }

  foreach ($value as $body) {
    foreach ((array)$body as $contents) {
      if (stripos($contents, $search) !== false) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: getting this warning PHP Warning:  stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given i

Comment: @sujara you can do `var_dump($value)` to figure out why that would happen

Comment: i have  var_dump($element); and in fact it is array as options are appearinbg three times for three product, instead of sttripos i am going to try in_array that should work https://paiza.io/projects/X0V69HyXUAgojp7afVJ4aQ

Comment: oh, i know why .. instead of `array(...)`, use `(array)...`

Comment: i was right, in_array has worked. apart from that $value = array($el[$key][0][$attr]); the 0 will filter only first element so i will be using || to include all others

Comment: i have already accepted but i did not understand ur comment. any link to documentation  instead of array(...), use (array)

Comment: oh, it’s a type cast ... existing array won’t be changed, but non-array items would be turned into single element arrays .. have updated the answer

Comment: is there anyway other element can be filtered (array)$el[$key][0][$attr];    as zero limits filtering of only first element

Comment: the code u gave above will not work for keyword blue as it is second array. not first. it will work if we search 12, 24 or 36 as its first array so  (array)$el[$key][0][$attr]; works but for blue we need  (array)$el[$key][1][$attr]; so i was thinking can we make it to work for 0,1,2 i am thinking to run for loop for that

Comment: oh, i overlooked that completely ... then you’d need to iterate over the outer array as well

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you have a multidimensional array and you're not iterating on all the levels. To make this work, I had to rework the entire logic, but I did in hope this will be a good learning exercise.

The `array_filter` function only works with the given level. You could keep it, but I'll propose a solution that merely uses nested loops:

```php
/**
 * Selects products where options match the searched one by removing the ones that don't match.
 */
function selectProductsWithMatchingOptions(array $products, string $filterName, string $filterValue): array
{
    foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
        if (!hasMatchingOption($product['options'], $filterName, $filterValue)) {
            unset($products[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $products;
}

/**
 * Checks whether the searched filter is within any of the options for the product.
 */
function hasMatchingOption(array $options, string $filterName, string $filterValue): bool
{
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        // this part takes care of "values", which is an array
        if (is_array($option[$filterName]) && valueIsListed($option[$filterName], $filterValue)) {
            return true;
        // this part takes care of "name", which is a string
        } elseif (is_string($option[$filterName]) && stringMatches($filterValue, $option[$filterName])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if a value is in the list of values.
 */
function valueIsListed(array $values, string $filterValue): bool
{
    // we have to iterate and check with stripos because in_array can't handle case
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (stringMatches($filterValue, $value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function stringMatches(string $needle, string $haystack): bool
{
    return stripos($needle, $haystack) !== false;
}
```

Now if you test this with your array:

`$filtered = selectProductsWithMatchingOptions($array, 'name', 'mAterial');`

or

`$filtered = selectProductsWithMatchingOptions($array, 'values', 'BLUE');`

dumping `$filtered` should show desired results.

I've made a couple of functions because I prefer extracting smaller pieces of logic. It makes for cleaner code. The alternative would be storing boolean values in variables to know whether we've found a match or not and that tends to lower readability. Plus, this way we can abandon the loop more elegantly, by returning `true` as soon as we find a match. That's nicer than having to `break`, potentially through multiple levels.

Note that I haven't passed the `'options'` key as a parameter, because it's the only one that can be iterated - this function won't work for `'id'` or `'title'`. It can be modified to handle those too, but I'll leave that up to you.

Also note that this functionality would still work even if the number of options changes (you mentioned in the comment that max is 3), because it is agnostic of the number of elements. Always aim for more general solutions whenever it doesn't require too much effort. You'll thank yourself later.